# Github Pages Configuration

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I use GitHub pages to host React project, but when I add a custom domain I get a problem. The custom domain is taken on GoDaddy, I added all DNS records there. CNAME, A, and AAAA.

Also, I set redirection from non-www to www with a redirect option, because CNAME doesn't allow to use @ and to point to www. But when I access the website I get an SSL error problem that connection is not secure. GitHub shows the status "DNS check successful" so that part is done correctly.

When you enter the website it shows

> This server could not prove that it is customdomain.com; its security
> certificate is from *.github.io. This may be caused by a
> misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

I see that GoDaddy told that he will not forward SSL on this way. So that is my other option?
[image: GoDaddy problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoDaddy has specific settings. There you can't set CNAME record with @. If you already use the forwarding option from GoDaddy please delete that. They will delete also one A record, but all GitHub A records too.

You need to remove all A record if there are any that isn't yours and add again GitHub A records.

It should take some time to generate everything but it will work for sure.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried to remove forwarding but I didn't see that GoDaddy let some A record, but remove others. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about obtaining an SSL Certificate first. You need SSL certificate for your custom domain.

Comment: Website has SSL certificate. GitHub pages provide that sucessfully. It shows this: This server could not prove that it is customdomain.com; its security certificate is from *.github.io. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.